# R geosphere package: find a point that is a given distance away from a great circle

Tags: r, geolocation, geometry, geospatial, geo

Suppose we know the longitudes/latitudes of two points p1 (-104.673178,39.861656), p2 (-87.904842, 41.978603), we want to find the coordinates of P3 which is 100Km away from the great circle determined by p1 and p2. It is also required that the closest point in the great circle to p3 is p2.

Here is my way to find p3:

First use ***finalBearing*** function to find the final bearing of the great circle at p2.

```
fbearing=finalBearing(p1,p2,sphere=TRUE)
```

fbearing=139.4564

Because the closest point in the great circle to p3 is p2, angle p3-p2-p1 should equal to 90 degree (is it true?). We can then use ***destPoint*** to find p3

```
p3=destPoint(p2,-(180-fbearing)-90,100*1000,r=6378137,sphere=TRUE)
```

p3=(-105.555,39.27437)

However, when I use ***dist2gc*** to calculate the distance between a point and a great circle

```
dist2gc(p1, p2, p3, r=R)
```

The answer is -100106.4, not -100000.

Is my way to find p3 wrong ? Or is 106 meter is acceptable error?

The link of geosphere package:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geosphere/geosphere.pdf

Comment: in general there are two continua of such points?

Comment: also, you mean 100km away _on the surface_, or 100 km away, euclidean distance

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes, there are generally two such points, I just want to find one of them. I mean 100 km away on the surface.

Comment: two _continua_. e.g., *every* point on _both_ the tropics of cancer and capricorn are the same distance from the equator...

Comment: @MichaelChirico Sorry for the confusion. It is also required that the closest point on the great circle to p3 is p2. Therefore, there are two points (two p3) that satisfy this condition.

Comment: 0.1% error would be acceptable in most situations, especially when the Earth is a oblate spheroid.

Comment: @davidstrachan Here we are finding the point on a sphere, not oblate spheroid.

Comment: I am curious are the authors of this package using some approximation formulas to calculate the distance/bearing?

Comment: 0.1% error is still negligible for a sphere. The library linked to is designed for spherical trigonometry for **geographic** applications.

Comment: @davidstrachan Got it, thank you. I get used to functions that could give me error within 10^-6 or lower...  :)